# Fetch api call: switch absolute path to relative path

Tags: reactjs, fetch, next.js

I have created API endpoints under my pages/api folder, and am calling them using fetch()

My code (calling the api endpoint from a page):

```
try {
    const res_all_data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/all_data', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
    json_all_data = await res_all_data.json();
}
```

Fetch works perfectly on my localhost with absolute routing, but not with relative routing (ie I want to use "/api/all_data" instead of "http://localhost:3000/api/all_data").

I need to switch to relative routing for deployment!

(Here's the API endpoint file, just in case:

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import database from '../../middleware/database_middleware';

const handler_all = nextConnect();

handler_all.use(database);

handler_all.get(async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const projection = { "Name":1, "First Name":1, "Last Name":1, "Admin Settings Public": 1, "Personal Profile":1};
        let doc = await req.db.collection("Volunteers").find({}).project(projection).toArray()
        res.json(doc); 
    }
    catch {
        res.send("Error");
    }

});

export default handler_all;
```